# Face 3d reconstruction

Tags: 3d, 3d-reconstruction

I've got a webcam that rotates at given angular steps around a person's head and acquires a picture for each step.

I'm searching for a free and opensource library that, starting from the set of acquired images, makes me able to generate a 3d surface that represents the person's head, or at least a well defined 3D points cloud.

Any 3d format is accepted, even if WPF XAML would be preferable.
I've searched for hours on the web, but all I found are tenths of academical documents and hundreds of broken links...

I tried MeshLab, AForge.NET, EmGUCV , OpenVis3D, but no one contained the desired function, nor a good implementation for the basic techniques (such for example dense features 3D triangularizations)

Any suggestion ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe there is a set of libraries you could suggest me to implement the different steps described in this paper http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~kucuktun/papers/facereconstruction.pdf ?

Comment: You can try Structure from motion libs, but I think when you working with faces you can try AAM\ASM approaches to fit faces in 2d and then project them to 3D.

Comment: Thanks mrgloom for your feedback, but I haven't the time to implement AAM/ASM by myself.
I'll check Structure

Answer (score 4):

Can't give you an open and shut library to solve it, but I can point you in the direction of a number of algorithms which might be useful, some of which have implementations widely available:

- [Visual Hull](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/A.Hilton/research.html) ([code](http://perception.inrialpes.fr/people/Franco/EPVH/))
- [Shape from shading](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=8407) ([code](http://server.cs.ucf.edu/~vision/source.html#Shape%20from%20Shading))
- [Structured light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_light) might be of interest if you can control the acquisition suitably

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I can't afford the needed time to study and try those algorithms, since the project is short in time. That's why i need for a ready-to use solution, even if partial.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need source access, you can start with VisualSfM and pass all relevant command line parameters through an `exec()` call: 
http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~ccwu/vsfm/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately I need the sources